# How to check whether two std::vectors are equal in less than O(n) time complexity

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o, stdvector

We can compare two vector using for loop like this

```
    bool checkEquality(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B){
         if(A.size() != B.size())
             return false;
         int i=0,j=0;
         while(i<A.size() && j<B.size()){
             if(A[i++] != B[j++])
                 return false;
         return true;
    }
```

but this take O(n) time if elements in vector is n
I want to know is there any better way to check whether two vectors are equal or not

and plus what is the time complexity for this code snippet

```
if(A==B) 
   return true;
else 
   return false;
```

is the above code works faster than O(n)

Comment: No there is no faster way. The time complexity for the second code is O(N) as well, because it's just doing (more or less) what the first code is doing.

Comment: Off topic, but `return A == B;` is enough.

Comment: If two arbitrary vectors of the same size are equal, that can only be positively confirmed by checking all elements. Otherwise there is a non-zero probability of a false positive or false negative (i.e. of indicating they are equal when not, or vice versa). So worst-case complexity is O(n) (if vectors are equal). If they are not equal, then it is possible to stop checking on the first mismatch - which is what `std::memcmp(&A[0], &B[0], size *sizeof(int))` does (to return zero if `A` and `B` are equal (but that only works for vectors of basic type, like `int`, not non-trivial types)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any better way to check whether two vectors are equal

Yes there is: `A == B` works fine, and is much simpler than your code.

> is `A == B` faster than O(n)

No, that would be impossible in the general case.  We can only do better than O(n) if we know something about the data, such as that differences are always found near the beginning or the end.